# Incluir un template de Ionic

Tags: ionic

He descargado un template de Ionic aqui: https://github.com/arjunsk/ionic-shopping-cart-2. Pero trato de iniciarlo con ionic serve pero no me deja. La verdad no se como incluir el template de ionic en mi proyecto, no he conseguido información en Internet.

Basicamente, quiero incluir el template y correrlo con

> ionic serve

Tras usar npm install y tratar de correr ionic serve me sale esto

[image: Error]

Estoy tratando de ejecutar el ionic en este directorio

[image: Error2]

Que vendria siendo el directorio raiz de la plantilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iría bien que incluyeses información del error que recibes al ejecutar `ionic serve`.

Por lo que entiendo estás intentando aplicar ese *template* como si fuese un tema de Wordpress que solo te cambia la apariencia de la página.

En lugar de eso, deberías clonar el proyecto de GitHub y empezar a desarrollar tu aplicación sobre él. O por otro lado, solo coger las partes que te interesan y adaptarlo a tu proyecto.

Yo he probado de clonar el proyecto y arrancarlo y me ha funcionado bien con:

1. `git clone https://github.com/arjunsk/ionic-shopping-cart-2.git`
2. `npm install`
3. `ionic serve`

Te va a preguntar si quieres instalar @ionic/v1-toolkit ya que se trata de la primera versión de Angular e Ionic.

Comment: listo bro, revisalo porfa

Comment: Oh listo. Solo me faltaba instalar el toolkit tal como mencionaste. Gracias